# TypeError: this.start is not a function

Tags: javascript

Непонятное сообщение об ошибке. Помогите, пожалуйста, понять почему следующий код

```
function Clock(options) {
    var elem = options.elem;

    var self = this;

    var     flag,
            nowTime;

    //this.start();

    self.nowTime = function() {
            this.nowTime = date();
    };

    elem.on('click', '#clock-start', this.start);

    this.start = function(){
            console.log(44);
    }
}

var clock = new Clock({
        elem: $('#clock')
});
```

выдаёт в консоли ошибку

> TypeError: this.start is not a
> function

при этом если тело проблемной функции я помещаю непосредственно в обработчик в виде безымянной функции, то код работает без ошибок

Comment: @Sergey Kalinin, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 1):

Объявите `start` раньше `elem.on('click', '#clock-start', this.start);`.

Comment: спасибо, помогло